# Sass Separación según número de elementos

Tags: css, sass

Tengo una línea y 'x' circulos que serán creados dinámicamente.

La cuestión es que si tengo 2 circulos, uno deberá estar al principio, y el otro al final, si tengo por ejemplo 4circulos, cada uno con separación del 25%... vamos, que estén equitativos,  x/100.

Además he hecho una 'chapuza' que ha sido poner a los círculos un margin-top:-30px porque se ponían en la línea de abajo, ¿ cómo soluciono eso también ?

html

```
<div class='line'></div>
<clr-icon *ngFor="let circulito of steps; let i = index" 
shape="circle" 
 class='circle' 
 attr.ng-class="circle{{ i + 1 }}" <!--Aquí tengo el índice del array-->
  size="36">
</clr-icon>
<clr-icon *ngIf="steps.length == 1" shape="circle" class='circle' size="36"></clr-icon>
```

SASS

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.step {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;

  .circle {
    color: black;
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Img

[image: dibujo]

Se trata de una línea y que si hay 2 circulos, 1 se ponga al principio, y el 2º al final, y si hay x que vayan separados equitativamente.

Comment: cual sería el resultado final gráficamente? una línea horizontal con círculos por arriba espaciados equitativamente?

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**
para poner el primer elemento al 0% y el último elemento al 100% en la solución que encontré es necesario saber cuantos elementos hay. Tal vez se pueda refinar

## HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="step step-5">
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-1">1</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-2">2</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-3">3</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-4">4</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-5">5</clr-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="step step-3">
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-1">1</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-2">2</clr-icon>
        <clr-icon class="circle circle-3">3</clr-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## LESS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    background: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .mycontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin:50px 0;
  }
  .step {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -18px;
    height: 36px;
  }
  .step .circle {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
  }
  .step .circle::before {
    left: calc(50% - 18px);
    top: calc(50% - 18px);
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    content: " ";
    z-index:-1;
}
  .line {
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
  }

.step-3 {
    .generate-steps(3);
}

.step-5 {
  .generate-steps(5);
}

.generate-steps(@s){
  .generate-circles(@s - 1);
  .circle-@{s} {left: ~"calc(100% - 36px)";}
}

.generate-circles(@n, @i:0) when (@i =< @n ) {
  @b: @i+1;
  .circle-@{b} {
    left: (@i * 100% / @n);
  }
  .generate-circles(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

- En el html el div step dice cuantos elementos hay
- cada circle tiene un numero segun su posicion
- Less arma la combinación de steps y circles con 2 funciones

completo:

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.step {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -18px;
  height: 36px;
}
.step .circle {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
}
.step .circle::before {
  left: calc(50% - 18px);
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
}
.line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.step-3 .circle-1 {
  left: 0%;
}
.step-3 .circle-2 {
  left: 50%;
}
.step-3 .circle-3 {
  left: 100%;
}
.step-3 .circle-3 {
  left: calc(100% - 36px);
}
.step-5 .circle-1 {
  left: 0%;
}
.step-5 .circle-2 {
  left: 25%;
}
.step-5 .circle-3 {
  left: 50%;
}
.step-5 .circle-4 {
  left: 75%;
}
.step-5 .circle-5 {
  left: 100%;
}
.step-5 .circle-5 {
  left: calc(100% - 36px);
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="mycontainer">
      <div class="line">
        <div class="step step-5">
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-1">1</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-2">2</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-3">3</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-4">4</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-5">5</clr-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycontainer">
      <div class="line">
        <div class="step step-3">
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-1">1</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-2">2</clr-icon>
          <clr-icon class="circle circle-3">3</clr-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**aqui debajo la respuesta original que distribuye diferente**

usando Flex y englobando los circles en step

.step

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

esto es igual a left 0% width 100%

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

poner los children en una fila

```
top:-18px;
height: 36px;
```

le damos un alto y lo movemos para arriba así queda justo sobre la linea

---

.step .circle

```
flex: auto;
line-height: 36px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1;
```

le damos un alto al texto de ejemplo ponemos el z-index a 1

---

.step .circle::before

```
left: calc(50% - 18px);
top: calc(50% - 18px);
position: absolute;
```

posicionado al centro del circle

```
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
```

lo hacemos circle

```
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
z-index:-1;
```

definimos el tamaño y le decimos que se vaya un nivel para atras (asi queda detras de los números de ejemplo)

---

completo:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    background: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .mycontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin:50px 0;
  }
  .step {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    top: -18px;
    height: 36px;
  }
  .step .circle {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    flex: auto;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .step .circle::before {
    left: calc(50% - 18px);
    top: calc(50% - 18px);
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    content: " ";
    z-index:-1;
}
  .line {
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="step">
      <clr-icon class="circle">1</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">2</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">3</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">4</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">5</clr-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="step">
      <clr-icon class="circle">1</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">2</clr-icon>
      <clr-icon class="circle">3</clr-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Nota:**

Al pasar al less estas líneas:

```
left: calc(50% - 18px);
top: calc(50% - 18px);
```

los cálculos deben ir entre comillas y escapeados así no los calcula de antemano

```
left: ~"calc(50% - 18px)";
top: ~"calc(50% - 18px)";
```

Comment: si la clase `.step` se usa para otra cosa reemplazar el nombre, por el contexto me pareció que iba ahí

Comment: muchísimas, muchísimas gracias !

Comment: Pero como quitas las líneas de inicio y fin ?Es decir, que empiece por circulo y acabe en circulo.

Comment: ahi va un edit con el caso de 0% y 100%

Answer (score 0):

Mi propuesta es que dividas la linea entre el (numero de círculos menos uno) así obtendrás la longitud de los tramos entre los círculos,no obstante creo que deberías restarle a la linea el diámetro de los círculos

Comment: Ya lo estoy haciendo, tengo una línea con el width 100% y por cada circulo ( For ) añado un circulo, pero no sé como decir que cada circulo se posicione.

Comment: intenta ponerle como margen izquierdo (el numero resultante de la división de círculos entre la linea) * el numero del circulo (la i del bucle)        por ejemplo: si tienes 3 circulos pones el margen del circulo 1 a 50%*0 el del 2 a 50%*1 el del 3 a 50% *2